# Maven Multi-Threads in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I am currently developing a incredibly huge Java EE project thats makes the compilation of maven takes about 20 minutes. 
If I use maven from the command line
the time spent is reduced to 5 minutes using the "-T" option, which compiles using more than one thread. But in Eclipse to run a Maven Update or run a build continues to bring exhaustive 20 minutes.

```
I Tried:

   Add multithreading option in MAVE_OPTS environment variable, but without success.
```

Anyone know any solution?

Thank you

Comment: there is an eclipse bug open for that https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=380169

Comment: Have you tried the Threads drop-down list in the Run Configurations dialog?

Comment: how many modules? 20 Minutes sounds very long? Which Maven Version? How many Tests?

Comment: @khmarbaise About 150 modules. I'm using Maven 3.3 and i set to skip tests.

Comment: @gillesB This is embarrassing, but I had not realized this setting, thanks!